# Pattern.compile with no flags?

Tags: java, regex

I couldn't find this in the documentation. I need to enable case insensitivity, but only in special cases.

How do I call the method `Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags)` in such a way that it is equivalent to `Pattern.compile(String regex)`? Can I just use `Pattern.compile("my regex", 0)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - `Pattern.compile(foo)` ends up just returning `Pattern.compile(foo, 0)`.

It would be nice if the documentation actually said that, but that's what the implementation I just looked at does...

Answer (score 5):

> Can I just use `Pattern.compile("my regex", 0)`?

Yes.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) says

> flags - Match flags, a bit mask that may include CASE_INSENSITIVE, MULTILINE, DOTALL, UNICODE_CASE, CANON_EQ, UNIX_LINES, LITERAL, UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS and COMMENTS

0 is the bitmask containing no bits.

---

> I need to enable case insensitivity, but only in special cases.

There are a few different kinds of [case-sensitivity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) available with `Pattern`.

For more fine-grained control over case-sensitivity, you might need to do your own case folding or collation.

Answer (score 2):

The [code for `Pattern.compile(String regex)`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.java.html) is (line 1021 and following):

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex) {
    return new Pattern(regex, 0);
}
```

and the code for `Pattern.compile(String regex, int flags)` is:

```
public static Pattern compile(String regex, int flags) {
    return new Pattern(regex, flags);
}
```

so yes.

Comment: Please don't post heavily encumbered code.  Some of us may want to participate in clean room efforts some day.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Not sure I understand what you mean: "heavily encumbered code".

Comment: The code is distributed under a [license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/scsl-1-1-149938.txt) that comes with significantly more restrictions than most OS licenses.

Comment: I have taken the code from the link in my answer, which is "under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 2 only, as published by the Free Software Foundation". Is it still an issue?

Comment: Reading [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51354/open-source-code-posting-is-a-license-required) I believe it is fine.

Comment: if it's GPL, I have no quibble.